# Symlink to /project/current/web work but not to /project/current/web/app.php (Apache / Ubuntu / Symfony2)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, ubuntu, capifony

Symlink to /var/www/myproject/current/web/ is working but is listing the web directory (not good).

Symlink to /var/www/myproject/current/web/app.php isn't working and give me this error : The requested URL / was not found on this server.

no logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log and this line in /var/log/apache2/access.log  - 404 error

```
ip - - [17/Mar/2016:06:21:15 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
```

Here are the set up :

Symfony2 + Capisfony + Apache + Ubuntu 14.04

Here is my apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is the .htaccess in /var/www/myproject/current/web

```
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>

        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And here is how I make the sym link

```
rm -rf /var/www/html
ln -s /var/www/myproject/current/web/app.php /var/www/html
service apache2 restart
```

==> 404

```
rm -rf /var/www/html
ln -s /var/www/myproject/web/app.php /var/www/html
service apache2 restart
```

=> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

```
[Thu Mar 17 06:44:53.385300 2016] [core:error] [pid 19767] [client 88.14.213.213:51484] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The AllowOverride None was blocking the .htaccess

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to work with the vhost of apache instead :

It's from the symfony cookbook : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You let apache manage the document root, and you add app_dev.php to url to use the dev environment, it's convenient if you have another env, like staging, on to test the prod env sometimes

To prevent listing of files add :

```
Options -Indexes
```

to your directory section of the vhost